# Hiding user emails in PFUser class with CLP or ACL

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is it possible to hide the user email's (in `_User` class) from the public in a Parse app with `CLP` or any other work around? If I turn off the `Find permission` in the data browser users won't be able to find each others with the search function.

Comment: My practice is, let the parse user represent only the relationship with the user and my app.  Have another class for a user's persona to other users in the system.  That class keeps only the stuff that's generally public about the user.